# WP7 find control inside header of pivotitem

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

For my WP7 app, I need to find a date control which I have placed in the header template of the pivotitem. 
How do I access this datepicker control in the code behind for the currently selected PivotItem?

```
public static T FindName<T>(string name, DependencyObject reference) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    }

    if (reference == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("reference");
    }

    return FindNameInternal<T>(name, reference);
}

private static T FindNameInternal<T>(string name, DependencyObject reference) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    foreach (DependencyObject obj in GetChildren(reference))
    {
        T elem = obj as T;

        if (elem != null && elem.Name == name)
        {
            return elem;
        }

        elem = FindNameInternal<T>(name, obj);

        if (elem != null)
        {
            return elem;
        }
        else
        {
            //if (obj.GetType().FullName == "System.Windows.Controls.DataField")
            //    elem = (obj as DataField).Content as T;

            if (elem != null && elem.Name == name)
                return elem;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetChildren(DependencyObject reference)
{
    int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(reference);

    if (childCount > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            yield return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(reference, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any real good solution to this. I guess my initial thought was why do you need a reference to the DatePicker object? But I guess you have your reasons.

A possible solution though:
You could use the VisualTreeHelper to traverse the visual tree from your pivot item and stop when you find an object of the correct type (DatePicker). Create a helper function like this:

```
private static DependencyObject GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(DependencyObject startObject, Type type)
{
    DependencyObject parent = startObject;

    while (parent != null)
    {
        if (type.IsInstanceOfType(parent))
            break;

        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }

    return parent;
}
```

Then call it with the PivotItem as the DependencyObject, typeof(DatePicker) as the type and finally cast the returned DependencyObject to a DatePicker.

HTH

Comment: devcube, please see my updated sample in the question. I am using this code to find the date picker but it always gets the datepicker from the first pivotitem and not the selected PivotItem when I call using something like this:  RadDatePicker radDatePicker = VisualElementHelper.FindName<RadDatePicker>("radDatePicker", this);

Comment: If I use - RadDatePicker radDatePicker = VisualElementHelper.FindName<RadDatePicker>("radDatePicker", CurrentPivotItem); where CurrentPivotItem is set to be the SelectedItem of PivotControl, then a null reference is returned. :(

Answer (score 1):

The regular Parent/Child relationship doesn't really work for the Pivot control. What you can do is search for the DatePicked component directly in the PivotItem:

```
((DatePicker)((PivotItem)MainPivot.SelectedItem).FindName("DateControl"))
```

MainPivot is the **Pivot** control. I am getting the currently selected item via SelectedItem - notice that I am casting it to **PivotItem** directly, since otherwise I get an **object**. Then I am looking for a control named DateControl, given that you have a **x:Name** set for it.

All that needs to be done after that is cast the object to **DatePicker** and access its properties the same way you would do for any other control.